# DataTables Need to get value from cell in current row to use in another cell

Tags: datatables

In DataTables, I'm using the following function:

```
"createdCell":  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
    var row_student = XXXXXXXXX
    $(td).attr('id', row_student); 
}
```

This is cell 10. I need the value from cell 9 (which will be row_student). So, how do I get the value from cell 9, in the current row?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to make the var line:

```
var student_row = rowData[col-1];
```